# Outlook web Add In detecting daily mail missing

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I would like to develop an Outlook Web add In in Visual Studio 2022 for me and some of my colleagues. His job is to check a configured folder, each day an email should arrive in the folder otherwise a task/notification or anything should prompt the user that something went wrong.

I have made my research on Internet and I have heard that I need to set a background task using Graph API... I also know about the very basics of Outlook Web Add In project but that's about it.

To be honest I have almost no experience in web dev. I am more of a VB/C# Desktop developer.  So I am quite lost.

Can someone help me?

Best regards